# PHP: Cyrillic (Russian) chars are echoing as Question Marks. Why?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

I have a project with Russian values in the DB.
All I need to do is echo them, but it's proving more difficult than anticipated.
All russian chars are just printing as question marks. IE: ??? ? ???????
All English chars print just fine for each encoding I've tried.

To simplify my troubleshooting, I playing in my sandbox:

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=koi8-r'); 
//header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1251');
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');

if(!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'id', 'pass')) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

//mysql_set_charset('ISO-8859-1',$link);
//mysql_set_charset('ISO-8859-5',$link);
//mysql_set_charset('windows-1251',$link);
mysql_set_charset('UTF-8',$link);
//mysql_set_charset('KOI8-R',$link);

if (!$db = mysql_select_db('db', $link)) die ("Can't use DB : " . mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM book');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
    echo'<pre>';print_r($row);echo'</pre>';

    $str = $row['russian'];
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", "KOI8-R");
    echo $str;
}
?>
```

The table field has a koi8r_general_ci collation.
I tried changing it to ut8_bin, and utf8_unicode_ci.
Neither seemed to help, so I changed it back.

As you can see, I've tried several encodings.
I haven't found a fix yet.
I'm getting desperate :)

~ Mo

FYI: I am coding in NetBeans on Win7-64. Server= WAMP stack.

Comment: the character set of the web page where you are displaying, is important too. It's set in the html header like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Thanks Dan. That's set at the opening of the posted code (isn't it??).

Comment: Dan was talking about an HTML tag, not an HTTP header.  Double check your generated output.

Comment: Checked and tried ... still no luck.

Answer (score 12):

SOLVED!!
The problem came down to a simple hyphen.

As found on http://punbb.ru/viewtopic.php?id=1222
I changed this...

```
mysql_set_charset('UTF-8',$link);
```

..to this...

```
mysql_set_charset('UTF8',$link);
```

.. and everything works great.

(In the process of trying things, I also came across http://developer.loftdigital.com/blog/php-utf-8-cheatsheet, in case it's helpful.)

I hope this helps someone else at some point in time.
~ Mo

FYI: Here's my sandbox script which works great

```
/* SANDBOX */
if(!$link = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass')) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('UTF8',$link);

if (!$db = mysql_select_db('db', $link)) die ("Can't use $_DB : " . mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM book');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
    echo'<pre>';print_r($row);echo'</pre>';  // For Testing ---->
}

mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: Apparently I am not allowed to select my own answer.  How should I handle this now and in the future ??

Comment: there doesn't appear to be any reason why you wouldn't be able to. I took a look on [meta] but didn't see anything. Maybe you should check there as well.