# Zend Framework: How do I plug my procedural solution for cyrillic (russian) chars into my ZF project?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, character-encoding

I'm in my first ZF project, and ran into a brick wall with russian characters.
(see [my original post on StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392863/php-cyrillic-russian-chars-are-echoing-as-question-marks-why))
I switched to simple old procedural PHP to troubleshoot it, and now I can use a little help in getting my solution implemented into my ZF project.

```
// in application.ini
    resources.db.adapter = pdo_mysql
    resources.db.params.host = localhost
    resources.db.params.username = user
    resources.db.params.password = pass
    resources.db.params.dbname = db
    resources.db.params.charset = UTF8
    resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"

// in bootstrap
    public function initDb(){  // For Testing ---->
        /* Configures PDO to execute the 'SET NAMES UTF8;' SQL query just before any
           other query. If no query is executed on your page, this will not be executed. */
        $pdoParams = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8;');

        $params = array(
            'host' => 'localhost',  // TODO: get from application.ini
            'username' => 'user',  // TODO: get from application.ini
            'password' => 'pass',  // TODO: get from application.ini
            'dbname' => 'db',  // TODO: get from application.ini
            'driver_options' => $pdoParams
        );
        try {
            $db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', $params);
            Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }

        Zend_Registry::set('dbAdapter', $db);
    }

// my data table gateway
    class Model_DbTable_Books extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {
        protected $_name = 'book';
        protected $_primary = 'id';
    }

// my controller action
    public function listAction(){
        $DbTableBooks = new Model_DbTable_Books();
        $this->view->allBooks = $DbTableBooks->fetchAll();
    }

// my view script
     echo'<pre>'; print_r($this->allBooks); echo'</pre>';  // For Testing ---->
```

**[UPDATE]**

Here's the SQL for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `book` (
  `id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentID` int(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `russian` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  `english` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parentId` (`parentID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

INSERT INTO `book` (`id`, `parentID`, `russian`, `english`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Мэри имела', 'Mary had'),
(2, 0, 'Небольшой ягненок', 'a little lamb');
```

And here's the procedural code which works:

```
/* SANDBOX */
if(!$link = mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass')) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('UTF8',$link);

if (!$db = mysql_select_db('db', $link)) die ("Can't use $_DB : " . mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM book');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {
    echo'<pre>';print_r($row);echo'</pre>';  // For Testing ---->
}

mysql_close($link);
```

**[/UPDATE]**

Comment: Are you sure your DB is set at UTF8? I use a lot of Latin chars in my ZendFramework apps and haven't had a single problem with this.

Comment: And, by the way, yes ... the charset is set to UTF8 at the DB level too.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issues with french accented chars. My database was in `utf8_general_ci`, my connection in `UTF-8` as you do.

To make it work I had to run de following code in my `_initDb` in my bootstrap :

```
protected function _initDbAdapter()
{
    $this->bootstrap('db');
    $db = $this->getPluginResource('db');

    // force utf-8 charset
    $stmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo(
        $db->getDbAdapter(),
        "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
    );
    $stmt->execute();

    $dbAdapter = $db->getDbAdapter();

    Zend_Registry::set('db', $dbAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Aweseome! I'll give it a shot when I get back from lunch. Thanks.

Comment: No luck. Didn't work for me. I'll update my OP with the SQL of the table for people to play with.

Comment: You'r database and your tables are in `utf8_general_ci`, I have a project that has about every languages names in their native writings and I have no problems listing them. Just a quick question, you set your webpage charset to `UTF-8` as well?

Comment: Yes, my webpage charset is also set to UTF8.  Regarding the `utf8_general_ci` collation ... was that an observation, or a question ?

Comment: Yes, the collation on the DB and Tables have been ALTERed to `utf8_general_ci` too. (Not to mention that it works just fine with that procedural code I updated the original post with.)

Answer (score 0):

Probably sounds stupid, but try to put UTF8 in "", something like:

```
resources.db.params.charset = "UTF8"
```

That would be:

```
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.charset = "UTF8"
resources.db.params.username = "woot"
resources.db.params.password = "forever_alone"
resources.db.params.dbname = "wooot_10000"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
```

Comment: At this point **nothing** sounds stupid :). Tried .. but it didn't work.

Comment: Man that is weird, i sent you EXACTLY the code i use on my App, and it is working fine, are you 100% sure the encoding of the page, the script and everything is fine? Why dont you try using utf8_decode(VARIABLE) or utf8_encode(VARIABLE) when outputting in the view to see if it works?